# Not able to create a GPU instance on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am trying to create a GCP instance with an A100 40GB GPU to train a Transformer model, but I'm getting this error -

```
Operation type [insert] failed with message "Quota 'NVIDIA_A100_GPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-southeast1."
```

I have already increased the GPU quote for the region to 1 from 0 and received a confirmation email, and it is also showing up on my quota dashboard.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Error indicated the quota has not yet been updated; it is not updated to the 1 from 0 for the region.

These could be a few possible reasons for your scenario:

- Visit the console admin page from your console and select the project you are working on and filter for NVIDIA A100 GPUS and click edit quotes button and fill the form once again and raise a new request for asia-southeast1 region.
- Another reason could be that your Quota increase ticket is still in process.
- If the above two are good please raise a ticket with the [Google Support team](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

[image]

And check your requirements based on the above GPU regions and zones and try with different regions once. Please check [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones#gpu_regions_and_zones) for other zones and regions.